# Use Personal Access Tokens to authenticate against Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, authentication, passwords, azure-active-directory

We have Azure Active Directory setup. That works fine with typical username/password and 2 factor works great. Is there any way to use a personal access token (PAT) instead of username/password?  I see all sorts of posts out there about authenticating to Visual Studio Team Services, or GitHub, etc. using PATs. Curious if there is a way to pull that off when authenticating to a database.

Comment: The other thing I wasn't able to do was use 2 factor authentication with Visual Studio when making a database connection. When you go to add a connection in VS, it is missing "Active Directory Universal Authentication". I see that in SSMS but not in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL database supports Azure Active Directory Authentication, which uses identities managed by Azure Active Directory and is supported for managed and integrated domains.  Refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) :

> > Azure Active Directory authentication supports the following methods of connecting to a database using Azure AD identities:
> >
> > - Using integrated Windows authentication
> > - Using an Azure AD principal
> >       name and a password
> > - Using Application token authentication

AFAIK, personal access token is not exist in Azure SQL database and Azure AD.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't seem like it did :-(
I posted a comment above for a follow-up scenario I couldn't do either in Visual Studio.

Comment: that is a vs related question , i would suggest you close this thread(if reply helps, please mark this reply as answer) , start a new thread and add visual-studio tag